# How to avoid SMO generated queries going into deadlock mode?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo, database-deadlocks

We have .Net code that does database replication using SMO.
 We use SMO to extract schema from source database and create them in destination database. 
And in recent past we started receiving bunch of deadlock issue. 
On analyzing the deadlocks graphs we found that some system base tables (ex: sys.sysrowsets) are causing the deadlocks. 
On some more investigation we found that..there are some SQL jobs running on parent DB that alter few tables (like renaming column, creating new column, dropping and recreating index etc.) that will internally update SQL Server base tables. 
At the same time using SMO we are capturing definition of tables which again depends upon system base tables internally. 
This is causing deadlock and SMO is the deadlock victim.
My question is

1. Is there is any setting available for SMO that will avoid deadlocks?
2. If not is there is any simple alternate way to extract schema of SQL objects?

For you reference I am pasting the error and deadlock graph here:

> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.ScriptWithList(DependencyCollection
>   depList, SqlSmoObject[] objects, Boolean discoveryRequired)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.ScriptWithList(Urn[] urns,
>   SqlSmoObject[] objects)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.Script(Urn[] urns,
>   SqlSmoObject[] objects)    at DataMigration.BulkCopyTable(String
>   schemaName, String tableName)   at DataMigration.CopyTableWithData()
>   
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoMicrosoft
>   SQL
>   Server http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink2047611.0.2100.60
>   ((SQL11_RTM).120210-1917
>   )Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionTextScriptServerTransaction
>   (Process ID 379) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process
>   and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.

[image]

**Sample Code used to generate script**

```
var server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(srcConnection);
            var database = server.Databases[MasterDatabaseName];
            var table = database.Tables[tableName, schemaName];
            var pk = table.Indexes.Cast<Index>().SingleOrDefault(i => i.IndexKeyType == IndexKeyType.DriPrimaryKey);
            var scripter = new Scripter(server);
            var createTableScript = (null != pk) ? scripter.EnumScript(new SqlSmoObject[] {table, pk}) : scripter.EnumScript(new SqlSmoObject[] {table});
            var createTriggersScript = (table.Triggers.Count > 0) ? scripter.EnumScript(table.Triggers.Cast<SqlSmoObject>().ToArray()) : null;
            scripter.Options = new ScriptingOptions
            {
                ScriptData = false,
                ScriptSchema = true,
                ScriptDrops = true,
                IncludeIfNotExists = true
            };
            var dropTableScript = scripter.EnumScript(new SqlSmoObject[] {table});
```

Comment: What does your SMO code look like? Are you attempting to script an entire database in one call or are you scripting the objects individually?

Comment: @BenThul, as per my knowledge I am scripting individual objects only. Any how i have appended the sample code to the description of the question. Pls check.

Comment: What are you going to do with the extracted schemas if they're no longer representative of the database? In other words, can't you just make sure your SMO code runs only when the jobs aren't changing the database? The deadlocks are a symptom, not your main problem.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I am not extracting the tables whose schema is being changed by the jobs. The problem here is with with system base tables that are held by the jobs (as there are schema changes) and causing deadlocks when I am extracting static schema tables (pls check deadlock graph)

Comment: If you know the tables in question don't change, you can wrap the SMO actions in a `TransactionScope`, passing a `TransactionOptions` with isolation level `Serializable` (if consistency is important) or `Uncommitted` (if it's not). Disclaimer: I haven't tested if SMO commands can enroll in transactions like this. Another option, which is more heavy-weight and requires Enterprise, is to perform your actions on a [snapshot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms175158) of the database.